# Using multiple colors for highlighting

Tags: jquery, highlight

I have this example code to highlight specific cells of a table. Is there a way to switch colors or use multiple colors at the same time?

I need to achieve two things here. 1) I'd like to be able to set the color of the parameter groups (or parameters individually) to a certain color on the front-end before I click them. Up to 5 colors would be enough. 2)It is not important with parameter goes which color. Colors can be assigned randomly. I reedited this question to make it clearer.

Here is the fiddle page for the project: http://jsfiddle.net/max33/kjcyu3yb/

```js
$('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', check); 
});
    $('.all').each(function() {
       $(this).on('click', all); 
    });

function all(event) {
    
        if($(this).is(':checked')){  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","checked");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","");
    }
    
    //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");
    
    check(event);
}

function check(event) {
    var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
        return this.name
    }).get()
    $('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function () {
        return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
    }).addClass("highlight")
    if ($(this).is(".selector"))
        $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)

}
```

Comment: I'd really appreciate an expert advice, is that doable, if so any guidance would be most welcomed. thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement exactly?Sorry I didn't get you properly, hence asking for more details

Comment: Thanks for your question. If you checked the fiddle page, when you click a parameter on the left, it is highlighted in green, and this goes for the other parameters, too. I'd like to be able to highlight in different colors, some are green, some are blue, etc..can this be done? Basically, I'd like an option to be able to highlight parameters in different colors on the table at the same time.

Comment: Yes you can do so. See my answer below. It is a modified version of your fiddle. Hope you will get an idea from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different classes for each form element. Like I have used `highlight-x` for x. Then after adding general `highlight` class to all selected elements, I am adding extra class for `X`. You can remove all classes at once using `removeClass` with no parameters. It will remove all of the item's classes. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjcyu3yb/1/). Select all from first form. You will see all `X` are highlighted using `red`. If this doesn't go with your requirement then let me know.

Comment: I tried your fiddle, but it seems the same. may be you shared the wrong fiddle with me?

Comment: Thanks, Rinku. yes, this works, with this I can define certain colors to certain elements. but considering this is a short exemplary code, when we increase the number of parameters to hundreds, it would be quite difficult to handle all.and color switching wouldn't be possible. "X" would  always be red. I wouldn't be able to make it green again without changing the code.