# jQuery Search and Hightlight, 2 Colors - 2 Lists

Tags: jquery, search, highlight

I have some old code that I use to hightlight a list of words:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
 function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
  var skip = 0;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
   var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
   if (pos >= 0) {
    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
    spannode.className = 'highlight';
    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
    skip = 1;
   }
  }
  else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
   for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
   }
  }
  return skip;
 }
 return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
  innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
 }) : this;
};

$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("td").highlight("car")
 $("td").highlight("sales");
 $("td").highlight("income");
});

</script>;
```

Very similar to this post: [Search and Highlight in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery)

But now I need the same script to highlight a 2nd list with a different color on the same page. What I am asking for is very similar to this post: [Using multiple colors for highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560009/using-multiple-colors-for-highlighting)

Can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated answer based on OP's feedback...)

The quickest solution for you is to modify your existing function so that it accepts a 2nd argument specifying which CSS className to add to the highlight span.

(Or more specifically in my example below, not the entire CSS className, but just the color portion.  This is appended to the stem "highlight-" automatically to save you having to type the whole thing every time you call the function.)

So...

```
// 1. Change: jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
// to...
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat, color) {

// 2. Change: spannode.className = 'highlight';
// to...
spannode.className = 'highlight-'+color;
```

Your function now accepts a 2nd argument called 'color' and `spannode.className` is dynamic according to the color specified.

```
// 3. Add some classes like these to your CSS...
//
.highlight-red {background-color:red;}
.highlight-green {background-color:green;}
.highlight-pink {color:white;font-weight:bold; background-color:pink;}

// 4. Then call your function like this...
//
$("td").highlight("car", 'red')
$("td").highlight("sales", 'green');
$("td").highlight("income", 'pink');
```

#### Demo: Run it in [JSFiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/CookieJon/aLxwogz5/)

Comment: it didn't work. didn't even highlight, but idea is correct.

Comment: Did you run the code snippet under "Example"?  It works for me.  If it still doesn't work for you, let me know what browser you're using.

Comment: hi bumpy, your code words perfectly. the snippet was hidden so i didn't see it. the site is already running a lower jquery lib... the code still works without the jQuery 2.0.0 reference. should i reference anyways? thanks again.

Comment: sorry had to unaccept your answer. one of the keywords being searched is "a$$" and that messes with the page big time when it hits cla$$="example". back to the old code for now.

Comment: No problems. My bad, sorry about that.  But I've edited the answer so it should work just fine now, and with a minimum amount of changes required to your existing ciode. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: No sweat. Handy hint: don't use style attributes for your highlight types ('red', 'green', etc.) Make the names match their meaning, (i.e. 'eye-brow raising', 'offensive', 'x-rated', 'blasphemous') and sort the colours out later. When they change the spec later on you won't have to re-code, either :-)

Comment: bumpy, i just found out that the code is removing words in an input textbox before user submits... anyway to exclude that textbox from the replacement or can we limit to one element?

Comment: Hmm...  I've updated the jsFiddle example in my answer to include key words in textboxes, but I don't get the same bad behaviour you're describing.  Have you changed anything else in the main function you're using?  (Perhaps create a jsFiddle showing the problem?)